# What can be said about the inverse of the antiderivative of a strictly positive function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow [1,\infty)$ be (a strictly positive) function. Define
$$F(t) = \int_0^t f(s)ds.$$

Obviously, $F$ is injective and hence invertible. How does $F^{-1}$ look like?

Comment: If $f$ doesn't have an elementary antiderivative you won't get anything nice. I think this is hopeless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we know that $F'(t) = f(t)$.  We note that $F^{-1}(F(t)) = t$ and apply the chain rule to find
$$
F'(F^{-1}(x))(F^{-1}(x))' = 1 \implies\\
f(F^{-1}(x))(F^{-1}(x))'
 = 1$$
That is, $y = F^{-1}(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation
$$
f(y)y' = 1 \implies y' = \frac{1}{f(y)}
$$
And that's probably the nicest description you can find.
If we were to solve this as an initial value problem in the general case, we'd get to
$$
\int_0^{y(t)} f(\alpha)\,d\alpha = t
$$
Which brings us back to where we started.

---

On the bright side, this description allows us to find an approximate solution with something like [Euler's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), or perhaps just getting the gist of the solution by looking at the associated [slope field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field).

Comment: That was great thanks. Because actually I don't need the real form of $F^{-1}$ since I am using it to apply a change of variables so $y' = 1/f(y)$ is the only thing I needed :) Thanks!